# Or-tools Python Vehicle Routing Prob with Breaks

Tags: python, routes, or-tools

I am trying to introduce lunch and dinner time into my vehicle routing problem using Google or-tools. Please see the following code (for only the lunch time):

```
solver = routing.solver()
for veh in range(num_vehicles):
    lunch = solver.FixedDurationIntervalVar(780, 840, 60, True, "Lunch")
    time_dimension.SetBreakIntervalsOfVehicle([lunch], veh)
```

The code runs but the result is exactly the same as not including the above section, i.e. the lunch time is ignored.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never, but I think the True is the optional paramater.  Which means that the breaks are optional so it prefers not to do it to optimize your performance.

Comment: Make sure that you do not have any jobs which have a time window within your lunch time. For example if your lunch time is 780 to 840 with a duration of 60 then no one can do anything at that time. So a job with a time window in that range will be dropped or the tool will not give you a solution